# selecting the month day and year from a transaction table

Tags: mysql

I want to create two queries for my table which has fields name,surname and amount paid,the first query should select the day,month and the amount paid,the second query should select a month,year in that year and the total amount paid in that month,lets say john paid  on 2013-05-01, on 2013-05-03,while peter paid  on 2013-04-08, i want the first query to output

```
month and day   amount
  05-01          200
  05-03          400
  04-08          50
```

and the second query should output:

```
month and year   total
2013-05           600
2013-04            50
```

I know I can use the `sum` aggregate function to select the total but the tricky part is how to select the day and the month in the format above,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first query will be

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m-%d") AS 'month and day',price as amount FROM `tablename`
```

and second query will be

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date, "%Y-%m") AS 'month and year' , SUM(price) AS total FROM `tablename` GROUP BY YEAR(date), MONTH(date)
```

Comment: You answered it :) He could also use: SUBSTRING(date,0,5) and SUBSTRING(date,0,7) - maybe it is faster than DATE_FORMAT ?